# Bootstrap Carousel - Whole website jumps when image is changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Hey lovely StackOverflow Community.

I have a problem with my website. I added the Bootstrap Carousel from getbootrap.com and it actually works very well. But there is one problem. Everytime the image sitch, my whole website goes up and down.

I don't know what could be the problem, cause i changed nothing on the code from getbootstrap.com :-/

Sorry for my bad english :D Hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: Set a fixed height to the carousel, this will should this error

Comment: sadly not, it's not responsive anymore, when i set a fixed height.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Overwrite the Bootstrap class. This will solve your problem

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
          width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! With your solution i have no black bar, but another problem. Now the image looks squished, when i make the browser smaler :-/

Comment: Thats it! You're a genius! - Sadly i can't give you an upvote cause i have to less reputations, but THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :D

Comment: Weird that something this simple fixes a annoying problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My issue with the Carousel was not directly related to the image, but rather the content within it that was causing the shifting of the page. To avoid it while being elsewhere on the page, I just used JQuery to detect if I had scrolled past my carousel and to make it pause. I know its a workaround but its effective.

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
if($(document).scrollTop()>200){
    $('#slider').carousel('pause');
} else{
    $('#slider').carousel('cycle');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because it changes some class on the carousel items.
You can set a `min-height` to the carousel container (`.carousel-inner`) and it won't jump anymore.

Set the value that fits better your needs.

**ALSO:**
Seam like there is a little effect on the images, so that every time that an image change, it became a bit smaller. If you just want to avoid the all website jump, use what i said above, if you want to change the "change-of-size" behave, you need to check the class `.next` and (probably) `.right/.left` and see if there's a change of height. It is hard to inspect them from a live website, that why i'm telling you to check this from the code - Or upload the code if you prefer.

Comment: Hey, thank you! It works, but when i make the browser smaler, i have a big black bar beneath the image. - Where can i find the "next" class? In bootstrap-min.css?

Comment: to solve the responsiveness, just use some media queries to change the height that you set to the .carousel-container. After this, it should work as expected. 
For the .next class, try in the plugin css file. But i think that the better way is to use media queries in your style instead of go an change other files that could be update and then override your custom style